# fs watch: view actual changes

Tags: node.js, fs

I there a way using `fs.Watch()` to view the actual changes done inside of a file?

For example, if I write into a file `var foo = 'bar'`, how can I see that that was the actual change instead of just the filename?

Thanks

Comment: Not using `fs.watch`, no; it just notifies on the two types of changes.

Comment: Are you asking about the actual change in file content or just a more specific type of change (e.g. file was opened, closed, created, deleted, moved, etc.)?

Comment: @mscdex the actual change in file content.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do what you're asking. The best you could do is either keep the current file contents in memory or keep a backup copy of the file and then when the original file is closed (that was opened for writing), perform a diff between the backup file in memory/disk and the new file. Then update your backup file for the next time a change occurs.